# Find a node that holds a given string in a binary tree using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have this method that uses recursion to find a node that holds a specified `String` in a binary tree. The issue is that it returns `null`, when it should return the node that holds the specified name, and I'm not sure why.

Here's the method:

```
public Node getNode(Node currentNode, String name) { 
    Node retrieved = null;
    if (currentNode.getName().equals(name)) { retrieved = currentNode; }
    else 
    {
        if (currentNode.right != null) {
            getNode(currentNode.right, name);
        } 
        if (currentNode.left != null) {
            getNode(currentNode.left, name);
        }
    }
    return retrieved;
}
```

Any insight into what may be the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't you think you need the return value from your recursive calls? For something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest taking [tail recursions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion) into account, since performance-wise this is a major factor :

```
public static Node getNode(Node currentNode, String name){
    // Base case: currentNode is null, nothing left to search
    if (currentNode == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Node retrieved = null;
    if (currentNode.name.equals(name)) {
        return currentNode;
    } else {
        // Tail recursions
        if(currentNode.left == null) {
            return getNode(currentNode.right, name);
        }
        else if(currentNode.right == null) {
            return getNode(currentNode.left, name);
        }
        // Non Tail recursion
        else {
        retrieved = getNode(currentNode.left, name);

            // If not found in left subtree, then search right subtree
            if (retrieved == null){
                retrieved = getNode(currentNode.right, name);
            }
        }
    }
    return retrieved;
}
```

Attached is the full code which was executed on [an online compiler](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler):

```
public class MyClass {
    static class Node {
    public String name;
    public Node left;
    public Node right;

    Node(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        right = null;
        left = null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name = " + name + " hasLeft = " + (left != null) + " hasRight = " + (right != null);
    }

}

static class Tree {

    Node root;

    public Node getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    private Node addRecursive(Node current, String value) {
    if (current == null) {
        return new Node(value);
    }

    if (value.compareTo(current.name) < 0) {
        current.left = addRecursive(current.left, value);
    } else if (value.compareTo(current.name) > 0) {
        current.right = addRecursive(current.right, value);
    } else {
        // value already exists
        return current;
    }

    return current;
    }

    public Tree add(String value) {
        root = addRecursive(root, value);
        return this;
    }

    public void traverseInOrder(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            traverseInOrder(node.left);
            System.out.print(" " + node.name);
            traverseInOrder(node.right);
        }
    }

    public void traverseInOrder() {
        traverseInOrder(root);
         System.out.println("");
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Tree tree = new Tree();
    tree.add("a").add("ab").add("bbb").add("cc").add("zolko").add("polip").traverseInOrder();

    Node found = getNode(tree.getRoot(),"vv");
    System.out.println(found);
    found = getNode(tree.getRoot(),"ab");
    System.out.println(found);
    found = getNode(tree.getRoot(),"polip");
    System.out.println(found);
    found = getNode(tree.getRoot(),"java");
    System.out.println(found);
    found = getNode(tree.getRoot(),"zolko");
    System.out.println(found);

}

public static Node getNode(Node currentNode, String name){
    // Base case: currentNode is null, nothing left to search
    if (currentNode == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Node retrieved = null;
    if (currentNode.name.equals(name)) {
        return currentNode;
    } else {
        // Tail recursions
        if(currentNode.left == null) {
            return getNode(currentNode.right, name);
        }
        else if(currentNode.right == null) {
            return getNode(currentNode.left, name);
        }
        // Non Tail recursion
        else {
        retrieved = getNode(currentNode.left, name);

            // If not found in left subtree, then search right subtree
            if (retrieved == null){
                retrieved = getNode(currentNode.right, name);
            }
        }
    }
    return retrieved;
}
}
```

And the outputs of the main method execution:

```
 a ab bbb cc polip zolko
null
name = ab hasLeft = false hasRight = true
name = polip hasLeft = false hasRight = false
null
name = zolko hasLeft = true hasRight = false
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the return value of your two recursive calls. Otherwise you're doing recursion "for nothing" and throwing away the result of the recursion.

```
public Node getNode(Node currentNode, String name){ 
    Node retrieved = null;
    if (currentNode.getName().equals(name)) { retrieved = currentNode; }
    else 
    {
        if (currentNode.right != null){
            retrieved = getNode(currentNode.right, name);
        } 
        if (retrieved == null && currentNode.left != null){
            retrieved = getNode(currentNode.left, name);
        }
    }
    return retrieved;
}
```

The following solution is arguably better style because you leave `null` checks for a base case. Notice how you no longer need to check `currentNode.right != null` or `currentNode.left != null`, as they're covered by the base case after one more recursive step.

```
public static Node getNode(Node currentNode, String name){
    // Base case: currentNode is null, nothing left to search
    if (currentNode == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Node retrieved = null;
    if (currentNode.getName().equals(name)) {
        retrieved = currentNode;
    } else {
        // Try to search right subtree
        retrieved = getNode(currentNode.right, name);

        // If not found in right subtree, then search left subtree
        if (retrieved == null){
            retrieved = getNode(currentNode.left, name);
        }
    }
    return retrieved;
}
```

Comment: This will crash due a null pointer exception.  Can you see why this will happen?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Are you sure? I tested this and it hasn't crashed for me (yet)

Comment: Obviously this can't be called like `getNode(null, "foo")` but that isn't part of OP's question.

Comment: Suppose you _don't_ find the `name`, i.e. the name is not in the tree.  Then how does your recursion know to stop?

Comment: It returns `null` without NPE. If you think a base case is missing... it's not. Might not be the best style, but this is the simplest "fix" using OP's current solution.

Comment: Please don't use "Edit:" blocks: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post

Comment: @pkpnd thanks. Although I would argue if the second solution is better than the first, why not remove the first?

Comment: Because the first solution is more helpful to the OP (in the sense that it's more similar to their existing approach). When learning, it's helpful to first see a "minimal" fix before trying to understand a more advanced fix.

Comment: @pkpnd but then just mentioning the solution in a single line like: `retrieved = getNode(currentNode.right, name);` would be enough. Then you can present the cleaner and better solution

Comment: The fix is slightly more complicated than one line. Notice you have to add a check `retrieved == null` to the following if-statement. Hence IMO it was better to just have the entire solution for context and clarity.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

```
getNode(currentNode.right, name);
```

You call the `getNode(...)` method but you don't do anything with it.

## A better solution

If you are willing to use [googles Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) (must-have for every project in my opinion) and java 8, you can do the following:

```
public static final Traverser<Node> TREE_TRAVERSER = 
        Traverser.forTree((SuccessorsFunction<Node>) node ->
                Stream.of(node.right, node.left)
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

And then call it where ever you want to traverse the tree:

```
for (Node n : TREE_TRAVERSER.depthFirstPreOrder(root)) {
    if (n.getName().equals("foo")) {
        // todo: do stuff with node foo
    }
}
```

The java 8 way of traversing the tree would then be:

```
Iterable<Node> nodes = TREE_TRAVERSER.depthFirstPreOrder(root);
Optional<Node> result = StreamSupport.stream(nodes.spliterator(), false)
        .filter(n -> n.getName().equals("foo")) // find node with name "foo"
        .findAny(); // we assume there is <= 1 node, so we take any.
// node.isPresent() to check if you found a Node and result.get() to get the Node
```

---

## How does this work?

Well, Guava has this nice class called a [`Traverser<N>`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/Traverser.html). You just give it one parameter, which is the [`SuccessorsFunction<N>`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/SuccessorsFunction.html). It takes any object `N` and returns a [`Iterable<? extends N>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), which are the child nodes.

We use [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)s to do this. First we create a `Stream` of the two child nodes. We then filter them to only have a `Stream` of `nonNull` `Node`s and collect them in a `List` (since the `SuccessorsFunction<Node>` wants to return a `Iterable<Node>`).

This `Traverser<N>` only has to be created once, so we made it `public static final`. You can now choose an iteration order. We chose `depthFirstPreOrder`, which returns an `Iterable<N>` we can iterate over

---

If you haven't heard of `Stream`s before, I would recommend [this turorial](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/).

Comment: Well written answer! (+!)

Comment: Does your solution not omit nodes that are not connected to other nodes, eg the first node?

Comment: @KamilTomaszJarmusik what makes you think so?

Comment: Stream.of(node.right, node.left) - It probably does not include the first node. What do you think about Stream.of(node, node.right, node.left) ?

Comment: @KamilTomaszJarmusik no, a `SuccessorsFunction<Node>` only takes a node and returns its successors. If it were to return itself as a successor, you'd have a graph, not a tree. And as [`Iterable<N> breadthFirst(N startNode)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/Traverser.html#breadthFirst-N-) notes: `Traversal not terminating (if the graph has cycles)`

Comment: @KamilTomaszJarmusik If you are curious on how this works, I would suggest you read the [`Traverser<N>` java doc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/Traverser.html) :)

Comment: It works so that starting from the first node(root) creates a structure(Iterable) of nodes? Is not lazy?

Comment: @KamilTomaszJarmusik it is lazy. The `Iterable`s will only be created when the `Traverser` visits a `Node`s children. Starting with a `root`: The `Traverser<N>` returns just that node. If the `Iterator<N>` calls `next()` it will fetch the children of `root` with the provided `SuccessorsFunction<Node>`. It takes the first element from the `SuccessorsFunction<Node>` and returns it. The next `next()` call will get the children of the last child which was returned and so forth. Until a leaf is reached, when it will go up one level and inspect the second child and so forth..

Comment: If I understand correctly what the author wanted to achieve, the general case is: (1) "no" and (2) "yes", neither will work, but if you transform your node objects into a non-recursive form, you can use forGraph(). (from java doc)

Comment: for (Node n : TREE_TRAVERSER.depthFirstPreOrder(root)) structure is unmodifiable during iteration, so the full structure must be loaded? Forgive my inquisitiveness, but I check my knowledge and intuition.

Comment: @KamilTomaszJarmusik the nice thing about an `Iterable` is, that it doesn't need to know about all the objects ahead of time. It just provides an `Iterator` which will provide one object after another. It doesn't need to precompile the whole tree ahead of time! You can test this by setting up a simple example where you put a `print` statement into the `SuccessorsFunction`. You'll see it will only get called when that element is reached while traversing the tree!

Comment: In for (Object object: objects) then during iteration I can not add or remove an item in the objects (eg List)...

Comment: @KamilTomaszJarmusik I can't explain to you how `Iterable`s and `Iterator`s work in detail here. You might want to find some tutorial online. For now, just compile and execute [this code](https://www.writeurl.com/text/1v9lf9kzkp66i539h94v/z0b5p1q8jihmf9fdgita). You will see that the nodes are only expanded as the are iterated over

Comment: try: for (Node n : tree.depthFirstPreOrder(root)) {
            root.left = null;
            System.out.println("iterated over "+n.getName());
        }
        for (Node n : tree.depthFirstPreOrder(root)) {
            System.out.println("_iterated over "+n.getName());
        }

Comment: @KamilTomaszJarmusik what are you trying to show me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169546/discussion-between-lonely-neuron-and-kamil-tomasz-jarmusik).